# How to get cell coordinates when iterating in PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to populate and colour some headers in PHPSpreadsheet. The number of columns can be variable. It is recommended in the docs to style cells as a range so I need to know the coordinates of the last cell to do this.

I've tried using `getCellByColumnAndRow` as I iterate through the columns but this returns the value of the cell instead of the coordinates:

```
$i = 1;
$lastCellValue = null;

foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i, 1, $header);
    $lastCellValue = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, 1);
    $i++;
}

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.$lastCellValue)->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

**How can I get the coordinates of the last cell when iterating?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getCellByColumnAndRow()` doesn't return the cell value, it returns the cell **object**.... and that cell object has a number of methods including `getColumn()`, `getRow()` and `getCoordinate()`

So

```
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i, 1, $header);
    $lastCellAddress = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, 1)->getCoordinate();
    $i++;
}

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.$lastCellAddress)->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the cell value, you can use this :

```
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($intColumn, $intRow)->getParent()->getCurrentCoordinate();
```

In your case, you should try :

```
enter$lastCellValue = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, 1)->getParent()->getCurrentCoordinate();
```